# Create button with imageview and text html

Tags: css, html

I created a button have a `imageview` and `text`.
here is my code:

```css
.button-login {
    border: 2px solid #007ac0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: #007ac0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    padding: 1em 2em;
}
.csslogin{
    margin-left: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<button class="button-login"><span class="csslogin"><img class="csslogin" src="img\icon_lock.png" width="20" height="20" >Login</span></button>
```

Now I want set space between `imageview` and `text` in `button`. How to do it?
Thank everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use margin or padding between image and text. You should change

```
margin-left:10px;
```

to

```
margin: 0 10px;
```